# What permissions are required for validating Google Store In-App Purchases?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-play, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am trying to validate user purchase with the token received from the client (internal release).
For that I am using Python script with Google Python API Client (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

```
    import httplib2
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    token = "token received from the client"

    http = httplib2.Http(timeout=self.http_timeout)

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        "./service_account.json", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"
    )
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    result = build("androidpublisher", "v3", http=http)\
            .purchases()\
            .products()\
            .get(packageName="<package name>", productId="<subscription id>", token=token)\
            .execute(http=http)
```

The response I am getting from this call is:

```
HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/<package name>/purchases/products/<subscription id>/tokens/<token>?alt=json returned "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
```

The service user being used is give admin permissions to the account (for the sake of the test) in Google Play Console, and set to be "Project Owner" in "Google Cloud Console" console (for the sake of the test again).

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes it can take ~24hrs for the service credentials to propagate. Did you just create them?

Comment: Seems like this was the problem. Thank you! Any idea what should be minimal permissions, so it would work? Of course, I am not planning on leaving this user as an admin. And with 24-hours propagation time, I have little room for trial and error.

Comment: I believe it's 'Owner' permissions: https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials#section-2d-name-it-and-assign-it-project-owner-role

Comment: Care to leave an answer instead of a comment, so I'll be able to accept it?

Comment: I have just created my  service credentials  hours ago. That means tomorrow late afternoon shall work ?

Comment: what does the token mean in this case? Purchase token or client access token after authorisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Owner' permissions are sufficient to receipt validation [[Source]](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials#section-2d-name-it-and-assign-it-project-owner-role).

The error you're getting is most likely a propagation issue where it can actually take ~24hrs for the service credentials to go into effect throughout the system.

Comment: This should be updated: it even changed in the reference docs to "Pub/Sub Editor Role". In any case, it would be great if RevenueCat added some explanation why this level of access is necessary, since giving access to ones GCP project feels a bit unsecure.