# Required permissions/roles for Google Play purchase validation

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, in-app-purchase

I want to validate my Android app's in-app-purchases on the server using the [purchases/products/get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) method.

Based on the info on [this page](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started), I need to:

1. Create a Service Account on the Google Developers Console.
2. Grant access in the Users & permissions section of Google Play Console.

Now my question is:

1. What permissions/roles should I grant to this Service Account on the Google APIs Console?

   [image]
   [image]
2. What permissions/role should I grant to this Service Account on the Google Play Console?

   [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952212/what-permissions-are-required-for-validating-google-store-in-app-purchases/57100054

Answer (score 0):

**1. What permissions/roles should I grant to this Service Account on the Google APIs Console?**

There are multiple roles that can cause Service Account to appear on Play's `API Access` page, however Play's developer support recommends to use `Owner` or `Editor` roles (there's no resource I can reference to, as this is the answer I received by directly approaching support).

Few notes/observations:

- Without granting any roles, the Service Account won't show up in Play's `API Access` page.
- According to my tests, granting `Viewer` role allows to fetch purchases.* APIs. However, according to Play's support team: *"Using the `Viewer` role may result in 401 response code when calling the Google Play Developer API"*.
- I've seen many suggestions to use the `Service account user` role. However, this role allows to *impersonate any other service account in same project to perform any tasks using its granted roles and permissions* (from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role)). Not sure how it works for others - perhaps the reason for this is the fact that there's a Service Account with `Editor` role [that is created by default](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default) (and allows `Service account user` to impersonate it).

**2. What permissions/role should I grant to this Service Account on the Google Play Console?**

[This support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686) notes that access to the Purchases API can be granted by one of these permissions:

- `View financial data` - this permission is available for users with “App” access only.
- `View financial data, orders, and cancellation data survey responses` - this permission is available for users with “Account” access only.

---

Last thing to keep in mind is that access propagation might take up to 24 hours - therefore if you'll try to invoke the API right after the service account creation, you'll most likely get the following error:

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "androidpublisher",
    "message" : "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
    "reason" : "permissionDenied"
  } ],
  "message" : "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
}
```